# Why nothing changed after I called the fill function in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to fill those NA with the non-NA values below in the `V1` variable. My code is: `df  %>%  fill(V1,.direction = "up")`. But it seemed that nothing changed after I ran the code.

I tried these examples from https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/fill.html. It worked as expected. Is there anything special about my dataset? Does anyone know why the code didn't work for the following data frame? Thanks for any help!

```
structure(list(V1 = c(NA, "TMTpro-126", NA, "TMTpro-127N", NA,  "TMTpro-127C", NA, "TMTpro-128N", NA, "TMTpro-128C", NA, "TMTpro-129N",  NA, "TMTpro-129C", NA, "TMTpro-130N", NA, "TMTpro-130C", NA,  "TMTpro-131N", NA, "TMTpro-131C", NA, "TMTpro-132N", NA, "TMTpro-132C",  NA, "TMTpro-133N", NA, "TMTpro-133C", NA, "TMTpro-134N"), V2 = c(NA,  "126.127726", NA, "127.124761", NA, "127.131081", NA, "128.128116",  NA, "128.134436", NA, "129.131471", NA, "129.13779", NA, "130.134825",  NA, "130.141145", NA, "131.13818", NA, "131.1445", NA, "132.141535",  NA, "132.147855", NA, "133.14489", NA, "133.15121", NA, "134.148245" ), V3
= c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "0.00%", NA, "0.00%",  NA, "0.13%", NA, "0.13%", NA, "0.25%", NA, "0.03%", NA, "0.08%",  NA, "0.07%", NA, "0.11%", NA, "0.15%", NA, "0.22%", NA, "0.30%" ), V5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "0.00%", NA, NA, NA, "0.14%",  NA, NA, NA, "0.00%", NA, NA, NA, "0.00%", NA, NA, NA, "0.01%",  NA, NA, NA, "0.01%", NA, NA, NA, "0.03%"), V6 = c(NA, NA, NA,  NA, "0.84%", NA, "0.82%", NA, "1.44%", NA, "1.30%", NA, "2.59%",  NA, "2.41%", NA, "3.22%", NA, "2.78%", NA, "3.94%", NA, "3.14%",  NA, "4.55%", NA, "3.58%", NA, "4.96%", NA, "5.49%", NA), V8 = c(NA,  NA, "0.78%", NA, NA, NA, NA, "0.65%", NA, NA, NA, "0.89%", NA,  NA, NA, "0.27%", NA, NA, NA, "0.63%", NA, NA, NA, "0.73%", NA,  NA, NA, "0.72%", NA, NA, NA, "0.62%"), V9 = c(NA, "100%", NA,  "100%", NA, "100%", NA, "100%", NA, "100%", NA, "100%", NA, "100%",  NA, "100%", NA, "100%", NA, "100%", NA, "100%", NA, "100%", NA,  "100%", NA, "100%", NA, "100%", NA, "100%"), V10 = c(NA, "0.31%",  NA, NA, NA, "0.23%", NA, NA, NA, "0.34%", NA, NA, NA, "0.32%",  NA, NA, NA, "0.28%", NA, NA, NA, "0.45%", NA, "NA", NA, "0.43%",  NA, "NA", NA, "0.34%", NA, NA), V12 = c("9.09%", NA, "9.41%",  NA, "8.40%", NA, "8.13%", NA, "6.26%", NA, "7.52%", NA, "6.07%",  NA, "5.58%", NA, "5.06%", NA, "4.57%", NA, "3.33%", NA, "3.40%",  NA, "1.86%", NA, "1.80%", NA, "1.03%", NA, "1.14%", NA), V13 = c(NA,  "0.02%", NA, NA, NA, "0.02%", NA, NA, NA, "0.00%", NA, NA, NA,  "0.01%", NA, NA, NA, "0.00%", NA, NA, NA, "0.00%", NA, "NA",  NA, "0.00%", NA, "NA", NA, "0.00%", NA, NA), V14 = c(NA_character_,  NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,  NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,  NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,  NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,  NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,  NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,  NA_character_), V15 = c(NA, "0.32%", NA, "0.33%", NA, "0.27%",  NA, "0.26%", NA, "0.17%", NA, "0.12%", NA, "0.09%", NA, "0.10%",  NA, "0.06%", NA, "0.12%", NA, "0.02%", NA, "0.03%", NA, "0.00%",  NA, "0.00%", NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = c("rowwise_df", "tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -32L), groups = structure(list(
    .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
        10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
        21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
        32L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -32L), class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame")))
```

Comment: It looks like your dataframe is grouped. Try `df %>% ungroup() %>% fill(V1,.direction = "up")` and see if you get the expected outcome

Comment: @jared_mamrot Thanks so much for your help! You are right. I tired your code and it worked now. Just curious, how do you know if a data frame is grouped or not?

Comment: If you print `df` it shows that it is "Rowwise", feeding `tibble(df)` into your pipe instead of `df` solves this

Comment: In this case, when you type `str(df)` it says it is a "rowwise_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame". A "rowwise_df" is a special type of grouped dataframe (re https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/rowwise.html), so if you `ungroup()` your `fill()` should work as expected